# Trouble install mysqlclient in Cpanel

Tags: python, mysql, django, libmysqlclient

Collecting mysqlclient
Using cached mysqlclient-2.2.0.tar.gz (89 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Installing backend dependencies ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
Building wheel for mysqlclient (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for mysqlclient (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [43 lines of output]
Trying pkg-config --exists mysqlclient
Command 'pkg-config --exists mysqlclient' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Trying pkg-config --exists mariadb
# Options for building extention module:
extra_compile_args: ['-I/usr/include/mysql', '-std=c99']
extra_link_args: ['-lmariadb', '-pthread', '-lz', '-ldl', '-lm', '-lpthread', '-lssl', '-lcrypto']
define_macros: [('version_info', (2, 2, 0, 'final', 0)), ('**version**', '2.2.0')]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb
copying src/MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb
copying src/MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb
copying src/MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb
copying src/MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb
copying src/MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb
copying src/MySQLdb/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb
copying src/MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb/constants
copying src/MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb/constants
copying src/MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb/constants
copying src/MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb/constants
copying src/MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb/constants
copying src/MySQLdb/constants/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb/constants
copying src/MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb/constants
running egg_info
writing src/mysqlclient.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to src/mysqlclient.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to src/mysqlclient.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'src/mysqlclient.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
adding license file 'LICENSE'
writing manifest file 'src/mysqlclient.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
copying src/MySQLdb/*mysql.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb
running build_ext
building 'MySQLdb.*mysql' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/MySQLdb
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC "-Dversion_info=(2, 2, 0, 'final', 0)" -D__version**=2.2.0 -I/home7/pahadisa/virtualenv/notice_board_project/3.9/include -I/opt/alt/python39/include/python3.9 -c src/MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -I/usr/include/mysql -std=c99
error: command '/bin/gcc' failed: Permission denied
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mysqlclient, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

```
type here
```

I was trying to install mysqlclient in Cpanel but I am getting the above error.

Comment: `ommand '/bin/gcc' failed: Permission denied`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would like to suggest that you review this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77610994/tying-to-install-mysqlclient-in-windows-11-getting-an-error/77744606#77744606). It may help you.