# tying to install mysqlclient in Windows 11 getting an error

Tags: python, mysql, django, windows-11

I want to install pip install mysqlclient but also pip install mysql on a Windows 11 Machine, I am getting the below error, I have already search to fix this error, but not get successful, how can I install mysqlclient? because I want to migrate my django project data to the mysql database?

```
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-Dversion_info=(2, 2, 0, 'final', 0)" -D__version__=2.2.0 -IC:/mariadb-connector\include\mariadb -IC:/mariadb-connector\include "-IC:\Users\Jamshid\OneDrive\Documents\My Programming Practices\Python\Basic CRM Tool\dcrm\virt\include" -IC:\Python312\include -IC:\Python312\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/MySQLdb/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\src/MySQLdb/_mysql.obj
  _mysql.c
  src/MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mysqlclient, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip install mysqlclient returns "fatal error C1083: Cannot open file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294268/pip-install-mysqlclient-returns-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-file-mysql-h)

Comment: I have tried that already, but unfortunately, no luck. This issue has existed for a week, and I have already done deep research in forums and here. None of them fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while trying to install `mysqlclient` for my Django project. After extensive research and unsuccessful attempts to resolve the problem, I opted for an alternative solution by using `pymysql`. Here's what worked for me:

1. Install the `pymysql` module by running:

   ```
   pip install pymysql
   ```
2. In your main Django `settings` file, add the following lines at the top:

   ```py
   import pymysql
   pymysql.version_info = (1, 4, 6, 'final', 0)
   pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
   ```

This configuration allows Django to use `pymysql` as a replacement for `mysqlclient`. Following these steps, I successfully configured my Django project to connect to a MySQL database.

For a detailed walkthrough, you can refer to [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNeVaTd_x0M). It guided me through the process, and I hope it helps you too!